# How to handle no response from the server for a request

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

How to handle, when the server is not responding for my XMLHttpRequest()-POST.
It's maybe server failure or server didn't accept my request. I have the following code which checks for a response from the server, but when the server didn't respond I can't see any error in console.

```
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") 
{
  if (users.result == true) 
 {
  console.log("Congrats!", " Your account is created!", "success");
  location.href = "login.html";
 }
}
else
{
  console.log(users);
}
```

When the server doesn't respond, the response looks like this-
 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Here is what I want.
In below code, I disable the register button when it is clicked and I enable the button once the server responds. If the server won't respond then the button remains disabled forever. How to solve this problem?

```
$('.btn').on('click', function f1() {
 //button disabled on click
 document.getElementById("Register").disabled = true; 
 if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") 
 {
   if (users.result == true) 
  {
   console.log("Congrats!", " Your account is created!", "success");
   location.href = "login.html";
   //button enabled back when the server responds with 'ok' status
   document.getElementById("Register").disabled = false; 
  }
 }
 else
 {
   console.log(users);
   //Button enabled back when the server responds with an error
   document.getElementById("Register").disabled = false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Your second if statement doesn't seem to be formatted correctly - it is missing a closing }

Comment: Is the server designed to throw timed out error?

Comment: The server does not throw a timeout